# Ruby how to validate date/time to be within at least 24 hours?

Tags: ruby

I have a date/time format in utc iso8601 like this:

```
 2017-07-12T13:30:44Z
```

And I'm able to get a "time now" by doing this:

```
now = Time.now.utc.iso8601
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare and make sure that the date/time I have in the first block is within the past 24 hours.

Comment: Don't compare strings. Compare `Time` objects. `t = Time.parse("2017-07-12T13:30:44Z"); t < Time.now && t > Time.now - (3600 * 24)`

Comment: If you have `ActiveSupport` (Rails), use `Time.parse('2017-07-11T13:30:44Z') > 1.day.ago`

Comment: @TomLord I'm not understanding how that will validate the time I have to be within the past 24 hours.

Comment: `Time.now - (3600 * 24)` === "Time is greater than 1 day ago". Your question did not mention `rails`, so I provided an answer in vanilla ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to handle this. In my opinion the easiest would be to compare the two datetimes.

Something like this:

**Rails**

`datetime >= 1.day.ago && datetime <= Time.now`

**Vanilla Ruby**

This requires you to mess with the date a little more manually, which responds in seconds. So 3600 seconds in an hour, 24 hours in a day.

`datetime >= Time.now - (3600 * 24) && datetime <= Time.now`

Essentially this is saying "make sure my time object is more recent or equal to 24 hours ago but not a date past right now"

Comment: Thank you for answering. Not understanding why people are downvoting my question.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  It might be a simple question to some people who have been using ruby for a while, but that doesn't mean it's simple for everyone. Good luck, Mike. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: I don't know Rails but have the impression one could write `DateTime.strptime('2017-07-12T13:30:44+07:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').between?(1.day.ago, Time.now)`. If so, that would be more expressive, imo.

Comment: Yeah, that would work too. In vanilla Ruby that would look like `datetime.between?(Time.now - (3600 * 24), Time.now)`